# Spring Data Jpa repositories using fragments how to apply query hints and entity graph

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Starting with Spring 5, we have the option to enrich our JPA repository with multiple fragment repositories.

The mechanism is quite simple: declare then implement an interface.

```
public interface CustomRepository<T,K> {
    // my very special finder
    T findByIdCustom(K id);
}
```

```
public class CustomRepositoryImpl implements CustomRepository<T,K> {
    T findByIdCustom(K id) {
       // retrieve the item
    }
}
```

Then, use it like this:

```
public interface ItemRepository 
  extends JpaRepository<Item, Long>, CustomRepository<Item, Long> {
}
```

Now, suppose I want to set some query hints and/or an entity graph like this:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long>, CustomRepository<Item, Long>{
    @QueryHints(value = { @QueryHint(name = "name", value = "value")},
              forCounting = false)
    @EntityGraph(value = "Item.characteristics") 
    Item findByIdCustom(Long id);
}
```

Since I have a custom implementation, the above query hints and entity graph, that work well on `JpaRepository` methods, are ignored here.

My question is:

**How to apply the metadata of the method to the underlying query?**

Comment: Not entirely sure what the problem is. The JPA `Query` interface has a  `Query.setHint(String hintName, Object value)` method. If you want a custom implementation of the repository method (rather than an autogenerated one), just use that method instead of `@QueryHints`. Similarly, for entity graphs, use the `javax.persistence.fetchgraph` and `javax.persistence.loadgraph` hints

Comment: @crizzis The JPA Query interface has indeed a `Query.setHint` method that I can use in `CustomItemRepositoryImpl.findItemById` method. The question is: how to extract the hint list from the annotations (`@QueryHints` and `@EntityGraph`)?

Comment: *Why* would you even need to extract anything? The `@QueryHints` annotation exists solely as a workaround for the fact that when Spring generates the implementation for you, you don't get the chance to interact with `EntityManager` directly and configure the query hints to your liking. When you're writing a custom query method, **you** are in charge of the implementation, there's no need for any annotations. Just write `em.createXxxQuery(...).setHint("name", "value").getResultList()` like you would write `@QueryHint(name = "name", value = "value")`

Comment: @crizzis You clearly didn't get my point, because my example wasn't clear enough. Please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: @crizzis The `ItemRepository` can have different query hints than, let's say,`UserRepository` - the last one extends `CustomRepository<User,Long>`

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking cannot be made to work using annotations, because they are intended to be used with repository methods for which Spring provides the implementation. It is neccesarily ignored by Spring for custom methods - since your custom code is responsible for building, configuring, and executing the query, there is no way for Spring to magically intervene mid-way and inject query hints. In essence, if you want two different sets of hints for a custom query method, you need two different implementations.

What you might try, however, is a sort-of-template-method pattern like this:

```
public interface CustomRepository<T,K> {

    T findByIdCustom(K id);
    Map<String, Object> getHintsForFindByIdCustom();
    // you'll probably need a default implementation for getHintsForFindByIdCustom here, unless it's possible to make CustomRepositoryImpl  abstract - not sure how Spring Data will behave in this case
}

public class CustomRepositoryImpl<T, K> implements CustomRepository<T,K> {
    T findByIdCustom(K id) {
       TypedQuery<T> query= em.createQuery("...");
       getHintsForFindByIdCustom().forEach((key, value) -> query.setHint(key, value));
       return query.getResultList().iterator().next();
    }
}

public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long>, CustomRepository<Item, Long>{
    default Map<String, Object> getHintsForFindByIdCustom() {
        return Map.of("name", "value");
    }
}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, CustomRepository<User, Long>{
    default Map<String, Object> getHintsForFindByIdCustom() {
        return Map.of("name", "some-other-value");
    }
}
```

Note that I haven't tried the above code. If it doesn't work, then perhaps you could try a separate implementation for `CustomRepositoryImpl` per each entity class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I don't expect "Spring to magically intervene mid-way and inject query hints". You can take a look at `org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslPredicateExecutor`. It's a fragment repository and here the query hints annotations just work. I want to obtain something similar without having to provide a special method to retrieve the hint map for each particular repository.

Comment: `QuerydslPredicateExecutor` works because again, you're not the one creating and executing the `Query` (a `Predicate` is not yet a JPA `Query`), Spring is

Comment: Actually, I can copy paste the code they use to retrieve the method's metadata (`org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadata`). It's working, but it's way too heavy. With many repositories, might be overkill.